# NextJS: Specify Common Rendering Template

Tags: reactjs, routes, server-side-rendering, next.js

Below is an example of a link structure that I am trying to work with:

`www.baseurl.com/pathname/some-sub-information`

I essentially want NextJS to render the file matching the `/pathname/` - so `pathname.js`. No matter what /some-sub-information might be, NextJS should render the `pathname.js` file, using the `/some-sub-information` as parameters for an API call.

I know this could essentially be done by passing queries through the link, and have it hook the the pathname, although I have been instructed by marketing that this is how they want the links.

I am at a bit of a loss how to do this, as this is the first time I am working with Next and SSR in general. I am hoping that there is someway in Next to specify that it should render a certain file when it hits the `/pathname` part of the url, and then just ignore the rest of the url.

This might be too much to ask, bug if there is any other way that I could achieve this, guiding information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I can think of is to add a [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) where you parse path like `/pathname/some-sub-information` and converts it into page to render `pathname` and some additional param `some-sub-information`

**server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);

    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl; // pathname = '/pathname/some-sub-information'
    const parts = pathname.split('/');
    const page = parts[1]; // 'pathname'
    const param = parts[2]; // 'some-sub-information'

    if (page) {
      const queryParams = { ...query, pageParam: param };
      app.render(req, res, '/' + page, queryParams);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

Params that are passed from server to client `app.render(req, res, '/' + page, { pageParam: 'test' });` can be accessed inside [`getInitialProps`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle) `query` param e.g. `query.pageParam`

So the page will look something like this

**pages/index.js**

```
function Index({ pageParam }) {
  return (
    <div>
      INDEX component with {pageParam}
    </div>
  );
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const { pageParam } = query;
  return { pageParam };
};

export default Index;
```

Having this custom server and `pages/index.js` (`node server.js`), go to /index/some-data-here will result into the [following page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gow9eekuye1cs55/Screenshot%202018-11-17%2021.44.17.png?dl=0)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Ohh, that does seem like a great way of doing it!
Thank you so much ! - I will test it out today, and mark the answer as accepted if all goes well !

Comment: Thank you so much @iurii - it worked like a charm ! However, I did get warnings regarding `url` being depreciated, so ended up running the component through the `withRouter` from `next/router`, which solved that issue. So rather than using `getInitialProps`, I `export default withRouter(Index);`, which allows me access to the router router props, which contains the same information.